# Appending integer many times to list in for loop depending on dynamic value

Tags: python

I have qty as a dynamic string, it can change. And I have a loop that adds products to the list(product is an integer). The goal I need to achieve is to add the SAME product to the list as much as times as qty equals to.

In my example, I need to add a product to product_ist 5 times.

```
product_list = []

for product in products:
    qty = '5' # dynamic , will change each time when entering the loop and its a string
    product_list.append(product) # 5 times
```

is there a way to do it? because I can't figure out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To *repeat list item a number of times*:

```
product_list = []

for product in (1, 2, 3):
    qty = '5' # dynamic , will change each time when entering the loop
    product_list.extend([product] * int(qty))
```

The same can be achieved with convenient [`itertools.repeat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat) function:

```
from itertools import repeat

product_list = []

for product in (1, 2, 3):
    qty = '5' # dynamic , will change each time when entering the loop
    product_list.extend(itertools.repeat(product, int(qty)))
```

---

```
print(product_list)
```

The output (same for both approaches):

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution as close as possible to your request:

```
product_list = []
products = ["product_one", "product_two"]


for product in products:
    qty = '5'
    qty = int(qty)
    for counter in range(qty):
        product_list.append(product)

print(product_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `range`

**Ex:**

```
product_list = []

for product in products:
    qty = 5 # dynamic , will change each time when entering the loop
    for _ in range(qty):
        product_list.append(product) # 5 times
```